# How to improve performance of count query

Tags: graph, gremlin, janusgraph

The objective of the query is to find the count of nodes and edges returned.
The query is as follows:

```
g.inject(1).union(V().has('property1', 'A').aggregate('v').outE().has('property1', 'E').aggregate('e').inV().has('property1', 'B').aggregate('v')).select('v').dedup().as('vertexCount').select('e').dedup().as('edgeCount').select('vertexCount','edgeCount').by(unfold().count())
```

Output: vertexCount: 200k edgeCount: 250k
Time took: 1.5 mins

I was trying to optimize the query and tried the following:

```
g.inject(1).union(V().has('property1', 'A').as('v1').outE().has('property1', 'E').as('e').inV().has('property1', 'B').as('v2')).select('v1','e','v2').by(valueMap().by(unfold())).count()
```

Output: 250k
Time Took: 30 sec
It's returning the edge count only.

How can we optimize the query to return both vertex and edge count and also limit on vertex or edge if required??

Comment: Are you just looking for a count of all vertices where `property1` is `A` or `B` and the edges where `property1' = `E` or do you only want the count if the A-E->B?

Comment: I am looking for the second option want the count if the A-E->B

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I have anything ground breaking to offer but it seems like your second query could get faster just by removing processing unneeded for counting:

```
g.V().has('property1', 'A').
  outE().has('property1', 'E').
  inV().has('property1', 'B').
  count()
```

I would imagine that if "property1" (for "A") was indexed the removal of `inject()`/`union()` would allow that index to get a hit (not sure JanusGraph will optimize that query as it is with the `inject()`/`union()` and neither seem to serve a purpose). Depending on the nature of "property1" for "E" a [vertex centric index](https://docs.janusgraph.org/index-management/index-performance/#vertex-centric-indexes) there might also be helpful. The `select().by()` seems like an unnecessary and potentially costly transform because it enables path tracking and forces an added `Map` transform which you just throw away in the `count()`

Your comment indicates that you need the count of the source vertex as well as the edge. Perhaps something like this would work:

```
gremlin> g.V(1).aggregate('e').by(constant(1)).
......1>   outE().
......2>   inV().count().
......3>   math("(2 * _) + x").
......4>     by().
......5>     by(select('e').unfold().sum()) 
==>7.0
```

The `aggregate()` just holds a "1" for each source vertex in a list which you `sum()` later in the `math()` step. Since the number of edges should equate to the number of `inV()` you can just multiply it by "2" and then add that sum to get the count of what you are looking for.

Or if edges can point to the same destination vertex, just extend the aggregate pattern to the edges and `dedup()` the `inV()`:

```
gremlin> g.V(1).aggregate('s').by(constant(1)).
......1>   outE().aggregate('e').by(constant(1)).
......2>   inV().dedup().count().
......3>   math("_ + source + edge").
......4>     by().
......5>     by(select('s').unfold().sum()).
......6>     by(select('e').unfold().sum())  
==>7.0
```

You could also add filtering if you don't want to count any source vertices that don't match a full path to the destination:

```
gremlin> g.V(1).filter(outE().has('weight',gt(0)).inV().hasLabel('person','software')).
......1>   aggregate('s').by(constant(1)).
......2>   outE().has('weight',gt(0)).
......3>   aggregate('e').by(constant(1)).
......4>   inV().hasLabel('person','software').dedup().count().
......5>   math("_ + source + edge").
......6>     by().
......7>     by(select('s').unfold().sum()).
......8>     by(select('e').unfold().sum()) 
==>7.0
```

Comment: I agree with the solution provided, but that will work only when we need to get the count only for inV(). I need the counts for source, relation, and destination all three in one query

Comment: updated my answer. note of course that the edge count is going to be equal to the `inV()` count so you really just need to count the source vertices and add them to the "edgeCount * 2"

Comment: there can be cases where two different edges can end up with the same destination node, hence getting all the counts for source, edge, and destination separately will help.

Comment: the pattern is the same. just extend it to count edges basically.

Comment: in the above query, all the source nodes are selected. I want the count of only those nodes which satisfy the outgoing relation and incoming node condition

Comment: then filter before you traverse `g.V(1).filter(outE()...).aggregate(....` or just drop all my `aggregate()` stuff i guess and do a `g.V().outE().inV().path()` then analyze that result to determine what the count is. i dont know if the latter helps make the performance any better though. you would want to experiment.

Comment: tried many times, not getting a solution. please share a query that will help

Comment: i've added a full example - the filter after `V()` ensures you won't bother to count any source vertices that don't have a route all the way to the destination.

Comment: It worked, I was wondering can be extended this concept to more than 2 nodes. For example: Nodes: A,B,C,rel_AB,rel_BC. Here C is the common to both relations. I want unique count of all C which are present in atleast 1 relation. I tried combining them with union query, didn't work out. Share a sample query based on your experience for above scenario

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237810/discussion-between-phoenix-and-stephen-mallette).

Comment: the requirements for this question have changed a lot of times given the initial posting. i suggest that you please accept this question as "answered" since it seems to satisfy that initial question and start a new question that fully describes what you wish to now achieve.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69454519/generating-efficient-count-query-in-gremlin-for-multiple-scenarios