# Generating efficient count query in Gremlin for multiple scenario's

Tags: graph, gremlin, olap, janusgraph

The pictures attached define the schema used for the graph with the following counts,
Total Nodes: 6.5 million, Total Edges: 3 million.
Based on the selection of nodes and edges, I am creating the count queries.

[image]

For example: Node1, Relation1 and Node2 are selected.
Query:

```java
g.V().
  has('property1', 'Node2').
  filter(outE().has('property1', 'relation1')).
  dedup().
  aggregate('Node2').by(constant(1)).
  outE().
  has('property1', 'relation1').
  dedup().
  aggregate('relation1').by(constant(1)).
  inV().
  dedup().
  aggregate('Node1').by(constant(1)).
  count().
  project('Node2', 'relation1', 'Node1').
    by(select('Node2').unfold().sum()).
    by(select('relation1').unfold().sum()).
    by(select('Node1').unfold().sum())
```

Output:

```
==>[Node2:7003,relation1:200166,Node1:27690]
```

Time required to execute the query: approx 2 secs

I want to extend this query for multiple selections described as follows:

Case 1: Node1, Relation1, Node2, Node3 and Relation5 are selected

Output required:

```
 ==>[Node2:7003,relation1:200166,Node1:22000,Node3:167, Relation5: 11000]
```

As Node1 is common in both selections, the output must contain all the nodes which are in at least one selection combination without duplicates.

I want to extend this query for multiple selections too including the whole graph. Tried using `union` but it didn't work.

If possible also suggest a query to return actual data for the selections.

Comment: Welcome to the world of Gremlin, get ready to be stuck in most of the advanced scenarios.

Comment: It would help provide tested answers if you could please edit the query to include a set of `addV` and `addE` steps that create a sample graph of the structure that represents the one in the photo but perhaps a bit more complex.